# Web Component Template Error

Tags: javascript, templates, web, components, web-component

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="test-component.html"> 
    </head>
    <body>


        <test-component id ="host">
            <p>test</p>
        </test-component>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the test-component.html file:

```
<template id = "template">
    <p> this is the shadow dom</p>
    <content select = "p"></content>
</template>

<script>
    var test_component = document.registerElement("test-component", {
        prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype,{
            createdCallback:{
                value: function(){
                    var host = document.querySelector("#host");
                    var root = host.createShadowRoot();

                    var template = document.querySelector("#template");
                    var content = document.importNode(template.content, true);

                    root.appendChild(content);
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

for some reason I'm getting an error on this line:

```
var content = document.importNode(template.content, true);
```

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

in `test-component.html` try this way to get template

```
var template = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector("#template");
```

Comment: does not work my-template.html:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null(…)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have a placeholder that acts as a navigation system for web components. The first component displayed (hard written in the html page) was loaded correctly thanks to Sigma's tip, but I couldn't get the second component (created through an event from the first component) to load correctly.

Here is how I did:

```
<template id="my-component-template">
    Hello World!
</template>
<script>
(function() {
    // Keep track of the document that contains the template
    let doc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    window.customElements.define('my-component', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            const t = doc.querySelector('#my-component-template');
            const instance = t.content.cloneNode(true);
            shadowRoot.appendChild(instance);
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't use template so.

First of all you can move your template into index.html then your sample will work fine:

```
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
      <link rel="import" href="test-component.html"> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <template id = "template">
        <p> this is the shadow dom</p>
        <content select = "p"></content>
      </template>

      <test-component id ="host">
          <p>test</p>
      </test-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

Live sample from http://webcomponents.org: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yugoka/3/edit?html,js,output)

Another option - create your shadow dom without using templates:

```
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="test-component.html"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <test-component id ="host">
      <p>test</p>
    </test-component>
  </body>
</html>

<!--test-component.html-->
<script>
  var test_component = document.registerElement("test-component", {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype,{
      createdCallback:{
        value: function() {
          var host = document.querySelector("#host");
          var root = host.createShadowRoot();

          var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
          paragraph.innerHTML = "this is shadow dom";

          var content = document.importNode(paragraph, true);
          root.appendChild(content);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Also this defeats the purpose of using html imports so this is not a solution.. why would I want to use web components if all my templates have to be messily stuffed in my index file? I May as well use jQuery to clone a div as do this...